# Is the operator $Af = \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(x) dx$ irreducible provided that $Af = f$ has unique solution such that $\int_0^1 f = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, spectral-theory, integral-operators

Let $k \in L^1((0,1) \times (0,1))$ be non-negative and such that
$$
\int_0^1 k(x,y) dy = 1, \quad x \in (0,1).
$$
Let $A\colon L^1(0,1) \to L^1(0,1)$ be defined by
$$
Af(y) = \int_0^1 k(x,y) f(x) dx, \quad y \in (0,1).
$$
Assume that there exists a *unique* $f \in L^1(0,1)$ such that

- $f$ is positive a.e.,
- $\int_0^1 f(x) dx = 1$,
- $Af = f$.

Is it true that $A$ is an irreducible operator?

By *irreducible* I mean

> For every measurable $\Omega \subset (0,1)$ with measure $0 < \mu(\Omega) < 1$ ($\mu$ - Lebesgue measure), the set
>   $$
> I = \{f \in L^1(0,1)\colon f_{|\Omega} = 0 \}
> $$
>   i *not* $A$-invariant, i.e.,
>   $$
> A(I) \not\subset I
> $$
>   holds.

**Edit:** It is clear the the uniqueness of $f$ is crucial. If $k$ is $2$ times the characteristic function of $$(0,1/2] \times (0,1/2) \cup (1/2,1) \times (1/2,1),$$ then $A$ is redducible, however there are also many $f$'s such that $Af = f$.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but this notion of irreducibility looks very interesting to me. Do you maybe have a reference for it?

Comment: @Surb In general, $A$ is an irreducible operator in a Banach lattice if there is no $A$-invariant closed ideal different than $\{ 0 \}$ and the whole space. In particular, in $L^1$ every closed ideal is of the form $\{ f\colon f = 0 \text{ on } S \}$ for some $S$, hence I just provided this spacial case characterization.

Comment: @Surb These are nice books on the subject: Shaefer, *Banach Lattices and Positive Operators*, and Meyer-Nieberg, *Banach Lattices*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll have a look at that. I'm working a lot with the notion of irreducibility for nonlinear operators in $\Bbb R^n_+$. There, the strong notion of irreducibility have some striking resemblance with your definition (and I guess is exactly the same).

Comment: And actually, you might be interested to know that there are nonnegative matrices that have a unique positive eigenvector but are not irreducible. For an example consider the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
I guess that you should be able to transfer this counter-example to your setting

Comment: @Surb Thanks. I will think about this. But do you know how would I transfer the matrix into kernel $k$?

Comment: Not really... Maybe with some kind of step function. Moreover, proving that the constant function is the unique positive eigenfunction of such a kernel might not be easy. I guess there are some works on that. I would look for papers about generalizations of the Perron-Frobenius theorem. Such an irreducibility notion as well as a uniqueness result (and a discussion relating them) should exists somewhere.

Comment: @Surb Could you tell how do you prove that your matrix is indeed irreducible? I found (in Hogben, *Handbook of linear algebra* a theorem that says: Let $P$ be a non-negative square matrix with spectral radius $\rho$. Then $P$ is irreducible iff every eigenvector of $P$ corresponding to $\rho$ is a scalar multiple of a positive vector. It seems that your matrix satisfy the latter condition. What I do wrong?

Comment: Well, there are various characterization of [irreducible matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem) (but I never encountered the one you propose in your previous comment..). For example a matrix $M$ is irreducible if its adjacency graph is strongly connected. Another definition is the following, for $x\in \Bbb R^n$, let $I(x)=\{i\in [n]|x_i=0\}$, then $M$ is irreducible if and only if $I(Mx)\not \subset I(x)$ for every $x\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $I(x)\neq \emptyset$.